# Apply default value after field clear

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to filter by price. That is, the user enters the initial price and/or the final one, and receives a result that matches the price for this range.

I have already done most of the work, but I ran into a problem (I will try to describe it in full):
Let's assume without application of filters in a database 10 records are stored (and respectively displayed on the screen). When I enter any numerical value in the first field, the filtering starts (and we, for example, see 5 records on the screen). And when I completely clear this field, I again see 10 records. Everything is good here.

The problem starts with the second field. When I enter any numeric value, the filters are applied (and we, for example, see 3 entries). But when I clear this field, all ten records are not returned, but a blank screen without records is simply visible.

I have const MAX_DURATION = 9 999 999. This value is applied when I go into filters. But after I enter something and delete it, MAX_DURATION is not applied to the field. I would like that when I clear the field, this value is applied again.

```
    const MAX_DURATION = 10000

export default function FilterDuration() {

  useEffect(() => {
    var updatedFilters = { ...filters }
    updatedFilters.durationRange = { min: minDuration, max: maxDuration }
    setFilters(updatedFilters)
  }, [minDuration, maxDuration])

  return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <TextField
            type='number'
            label="From"
            value={value}
            />
        </div>

       
      </div>

  );
}
```

Comment: By clearing you mean that you set value of maxDuration to 0 is that right?

Comment: @TalhaFayyaz By clear, I mean when I remove all the data from the field. And it turns out that maxDuration takes the value 0, yes. Or maxDuration doesn't apply at all in this case. I can not understand

Comment: can you try adding simple if statement in useEffect that if the value of maxDuration is 0 setMaxDuration(MAX_DURATION) ?

Comment: No worries if you can accept my answer below that will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply try modifying your useEffect in this way:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        var updatedFilters = { ...filters }
        updatedFilters.durationRange = { min: minDuration, max: maxDuration }
        setFilters(updatedFilters)
        if(maxDuration === 0 ){
        setMaxDuration(Max_Duration);}
      }, [minDuration, maxDuration])
```

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid we're in a hurry. This option only works if the first field is empty. If there is any value in the first field, then the problem does not disappear anywhere. Can you help me solve it completely?

Comment: what should be the case if first field has some value?

Comment: At the moment the problem is this: suppose the first field has some value. Further, when I enter a value in the second field, the data is filtered. But when I clear the second field, the data doesn't change. That is, as I understand it, MAX_DURATION does not apply

Comment: can you add a console in useEffect and inspect value of maxDuration when you clear the second field?

Comment: I get it text: The specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range

Comment: ok seems like when you clear the field it gets NAN so you can change this const newValue = Number(e.target.value || 0).

Comment: I'm sorry, I misled you a little. When I add console.log(maxDuration ) to useEffect , I see there the number that I enter in the second field

Comment: ok what is the value that you get when you clear second field ?

Comment: In the event that the first field is empty: when I delete the value from the second field, I get 9999999 in the console.
In the event that the first mole has a value: when I delete the value from the second field, I get the number that I entered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247250/discussion-between-talha-fayyaz-and-paul).